# Как использовать document в Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom

пишу сайт, бэк которого на `node.js`, а фронт - `js`, `html`, `css`. Научился запускать сервер `node.js`, но пока не понял как сочетать его с клиентским js. Как я понял, всё пишется в одном файле, но как быть, если я хочу обратиться к объекту `document`, а мне выдаётся ошибка `ReferenceError: document is not defined`?
 Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на этом примере решить вопрос сочетания серверного и клиентского javascript.

Это часть моего файла index.html:

```html
<head>
    ...
    <script src="../index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        ...
        <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        ...        
        <input id="password" type="password" class="validate">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <a id="reg" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" href="main.html">Зарегистрироваться</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Это часть моего файла index.js:

```js
const http = require('http')
const path = require('path')

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

    let filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', req.url === '/' ? 'index.html' : req.url)
    // ...
})

// Попытка получить логин с паролем из html и вывести их
const btn_reg = document.getElementById('reg')
const input_email = document.getElementById('email').value
const input_pass = document.getElementById('password').value
btn_reg.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("email: ", input_email, "\n", "password: ", input_pass)
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server has been started on ${PORT}...`)
})
```

Comment: @entithat, а как в моём случае отправить запрос с клиента на сервер? Через ajax?

Comment: document не доступен в nodejs, по крайне мере тот что вы пытаетесь получить. Вам нужно подключать в html файлик js отдельный и там писать логику, а с сервером общаться через запросы

Answer (score 3):

объект `document` является частью [браузерного окружения](https://learn.javascript.ru/browser-environment) (этот объект предоставляется javascript-у браузером). a node.js это серверный язык (выполняется на сервере *([в движке если точнее](https://habr.com/ru/post/420123/))* ) и соответственно этого объекта у него нет. Вот так можно отправить данные с формы на бэк:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- подключать index.js не надо поскольку код внутри него исполняется сервером node.js а не браузером. когда запускаете, вы же пишете node index.js чтобы файл исполнился node-ом  -->
        <script src="../index.js"></script> <!-- не надо так делать -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- в action указываем роут по которому отправляем данные с формы. и этот роут мы обрабатываем в node -->
        <form action="/save-user" method="post" id="reg-form">
            <div class="row">
                <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="validate">
            </div>
            
            <div class="row">
                <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="validate">
            </div>  

            <input type="submit" id="reg" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small" value="Зарегистрироваться">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```js
let http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    url = require('url'), // чтобы отследить роут
    { parse } = require('querystring'); // чтобы правильно взять параметры из запроса

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    if (req.url == '/' || req.url == '/index.js') {
        fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, data) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html','Content-Length':data.length});
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }

    else if (req.url == '/save-user' && req.method == 'POST') { // когда что-то с методом POST "постучиться" в роут '/save-user'
        let body = '';

        req.on('data', chunk => { // когда "придет" часть данных. добавляем их в body
            body += chunk.toString(); 
        });

        req.on('end', () => { // при завершении получения ответа. (когда уже все части данных пришли)
            let params = parse(body); // используем функцию parse из модуля querystring
            // console.log(`email: ${params.email}\npassword: ${params.password}`);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(params)); // превращаем в json строку и возвращаем
        });
    }


}).listen(8000);
```

А если нужно чтобы клиентский `js` обязательно участвовал, то можно [отправить форму через ajax запрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1138451/319165).

Как видите "общение" между бэком и фронтом может осуществляться через "роуты". вы НЕ можете напрямую из бэка (этак из файла `index.js`) обращаться к элементам на фронте, так же, как и не можете с фронта напрямую обращаться к бэку. советую ознакомиться с [REST API](https://habr.com/ru/post/483202/) как со способом общения бэка и фронта.